# Remove both duplicates (original and duplicate) from text notepad++

Tags: text, duplicates, notepad++

I need to remove both duplicates like:

```
admin
user
admin
```

result:

`user`

I have tried but none works for notepad++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You have to sort your file before apply this (for example using the plugin TexFX).**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)(?:\R\1)+`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : Beginning of line
(.+)    : group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
(?:     : start non capture group
  \R    : any kind of linebreak
  \1    : content of group 1
)+      : end group, must appear 1 or more times
```